# Laravel not displaying style property when i use a dynamic variable

Tags: laravel-5.4, styling, laravel-blade

I want to display a variable hex color code into the border property of my `li` tag. But every time I try the style property doesn't appear at all in the browser. Heres part of the code

```
@if(Count($user->groups))
<ul class="list-group">
    @foreach($user->groups as $group)
        <li class="list-group-item" style = "border-left: 4px solid {{ $group->colors[0]->hex }} !important;">{{ $group->name }}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

The $user is the logged in user property which has a belongsToMany relationship with groups. The groups also has a belongsToMany relationship with colors. So i'm trying to get the users groups displayed as `li` tags. And then color the border-left of each list with the associated group color.

Comment: what does `dump($group->colors[0]->hex)` show?

Comment: $group->colors[0]->hex returns 'd43939' for the first list item and '27a236' for the second

Comment: milo526 thanks for that, i just noticed that i didn't have the '#' being outputted. I added it and fixed the issue